# For a ResponseCache policy, what's the default behavior if CacheLookupTimeoutInSeconds is not specified

Tags: caching, apigee

I'm working on a [ResponseCache](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/reduce-latency-using-responsecache) policy, and I noticed in the documentation that CacheLookupTimeoutInSeconds is optional. What is the default behavior if this element is not specified in my policy? Does it have a default timeout, and if so, what is the timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default timeout is 30 seconds